# EF6.0 Multiplicity complication

Tags: c#, collections, entity-framework-6, parent-child, multiplicity

I have a parent table called participantprofile with a primary key of userID. This primary key is used for a few child tables which are collections of records for each userID.

One of the child tables, participantaltemails can contain 0 - many child records of userID.

I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around why I continue to get a Multiplicity error saying "{"Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'participantprofile' of the relationship 'db_entity.FK__participa__userI__0AEED4AD' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1."}

When I go into the EF project to look at the relationship I see the following:

- End1 Multiplicity: 1 (One of participantprofile)
- End1 Navigation Property: participantaltemails
- End2 Multiplicity: * (Collection of participantaltemail)
- End2 Navigation Property: participantprofile

The error however is being thrown during the following statement which is making it even more confusing (thrown during the _de.participantraces.Add(_ra) line):

```
if (_ti.participantraces != null)
                {
                    List<participantrace> _tlr = _ti.participantraces.ToList();
                    foreach (participantrace _ra in _ti.participantraces)
                    {
                        if (_ra.participantraceid == 0)
                            _de.participantraces.Add(_ra);
                                //_de.Entry(_a.participantraces).Entity.Add(_ra);
                    }
                }
```

[image]

Comment: I would say stop using EF but that's not that constructive :) I've had the same issues but they were just due to bad config - are you 100% sure you haven't set the multiplicity to 0 or 1? Can you screenshot the editor/or include the code if code first?

Comment: I did database first, and yes I am 100% sure about the multiplicity I have the EF project open and looking right at it.

Comment: @Charleh I added the screenshot just in case my old eyes are  missing something

Comment: Does ANYONE have any idea how to fix this!

Comment: Well, the error message says `participantprofile` role has 1 or 0..1 - which is correct: `End1 Role Name = participantprofile` which has a multiplicity of 1. How do `participantraces` fit in to the model? What's a `_de`? There's not enough info here to answer the question but I'd imagine your issue is that you are attaching multiple `participantemails` via `participantraces` or something of that ilk.